# How to redirect an function call inside dll to the main app

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, hook, ipc

I am working with hooks rn (WINAPI). And some hooks need to be initialized in a DLL.
Inside the DLL, there is the callback function which is called depending on the hook installed.
But the callback is called on the other process so I don't have anything in my main app to react to it...

Is there any way to communicate back to my main app from the DLL?

I thought about IPC with shared memory but I am not sure if there is a better/easier way to achieve this...

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: `WM_COPYDATA` is the easiest; then custom Windows message; then UDP; then TCP; then shared memory, needs careful setting up and never store an address in the shared memory as each process will usually have a different virtual address mapped to the shared area and you will also need cross-process locking (system Mutex etc).

Comment: "*the callback is called on the other process*" - that depends on the type of hook you are installing. Some hooks are called in the process that they are hooking and some are called in the process that installs them.

Comment: WH_CALLWNDPROC is called on the target process. Looking forward to using WM_COPYDATA because this seems to be an effective solution for local apps.